# UITextView as own delegate means infinite loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, delegates

I have a subclass of a UITextView and I would like to make it it's own delegate. So that I can override the `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` method, and prevent consecutive spaces being entered.

In `[SATextView awakeFromNib]` (SATextView is my subclass of UITextView), I do `[self setDelegate:self];`. When I press on the textview to start editing everything freezes and eventually stops, and that backtrace shows that there has been an infinite loop.

It doesn't matter if I implement all delegate methods, just one, or none. Nor does it matter if those methods are empty.

Why does this cause an infinite loop? It only seems to happen if with UITextView (other objects you can subclass and set the delegate to self, and it won't have this problem). And how can I stop it? Or is there a better way to have this subclass not able to have consecutive spaces,

Comment: Think about it.  Hard.  It is possible to have a class be its own delegate, but it requires thought.

Comment: @HotLicks I have though about it, I've done it with other classes without problems? Can you help?

Comment: The backtrace should show you the loop you're in.

Comment: Why not make the host view controller handle these delegation decisions? Three lines of code later, and you won't be banging your head against StackOverflow looking for a solution to a problem easily solved by proper MVC coding.

Comment: @gschandler, I need to reuse this textview elsewhere, where it has a different host controller. It is used to enter a list of space separated tags, so not wanting consecutive spaces is a view thing.

Comment: @HotLicks, it does show the loop, which is an undocumented method, and I don't understand how I can solve the problem, knowing that?

Comment: Then, instead of making it a delegate of itself, consider overriding one of the UITextInput protocol methods. Without having done it myself, I would look first at `- (void)replaceRange:(UITextRange *)range withText:(NSString *)text;`

Comment: @gschandler, that method is not called when inputting text. It has to be explicitly called

Answer (score 1):

An idea... You could make a delegate Class that acts as a middle man between the real delegate and the UITextView (because you'll probably need to set the delegate after some time). So this new class will implement the delegate protocol, but it will also have a property for it's own delegate, so that you can forward textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:, and still do the work of editing the spaces in your middleMan class.

Comment: this is what I recommend. Create a helper class that implements `UITextViewDelegate` and enforces the behaviors you want. This class can have its own protocol if desired to send messages to the controller managing the overall logic. This pattern is useful in many scenarios, I use it for `UITableViewDataSource` as well. You end up with nice, tidy, reusable protocol implementations.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to subscribe any numbers of observers to an object. So it is possible to subscribe itself:

```
@implementation MyTextView 

-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame // or initWithCoder: for loading from nib
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textViewTextDidChangeNotification:) name:UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification object:self];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)textViewTextDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification*)n
{
    self.text = [self.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@" "];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the `should` methods which can't be observed using notification centre

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I  have successfully done this. I was only interested in preventing certain characters from being inputted so I only implement `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` and then pass the rest on.

```
#import "INFTextView.h"

@interface INFTextView () <UITextViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<UITextViewDelegate> externalDelegate;

@end

@implementation INFTextView

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.delegate = self;

    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.delegate = self;
}

- (void)setDelegate:(id<UITextViewDelegate>)delegate {
    // we always want self to be the delegate, if someone is interested in delegate calls we will forward those on if applicable
    if (delegate == self) {
        [super setDelegate:self];
        return;
    } else {
        // capture that someone else is interested in delegate calls
        _externalDelegate = delegate;
    }
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    NSCharacterSet *unsupportedCharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:kINFSupportedCharacters] invertedSet];

    NSRange unsupportedCharacterRange = [text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:unsupportedCharacterSet];
    if (unsupportedCharacterRange.location == NSNotFound) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    if ([_externalDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textViewShouldBeginEditing:)]) {
        return [_externalDelegate textViewShouldBeginEditing:textView];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    if ([_externalDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textViewShouldEndEditing:)]) {
        return [_externalDelegate textViewShouldEndEditing:textView];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    if ([_externalDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textViewDidBeginEditing:)]) {
        [_externalDelegate textViewDidBeginEditing:textView];
    }
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    if ([_externalDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textViewDidEndEditing:)]) {
        [_externalDelegate textViewDidEndEditing:textView];
    }
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    if ([_externalDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textViewDidChange:)]) {
        [_externalDelegate textViewDidChange:textView];
    }
}

- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {
    if ([_externalDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textViewDidChangeSelection:)]) {
        [_externalDelegate textViewDidChangeSelection:textView];
    }
}

@end
```

One big 'gotcha' which led me to this question was I was trying to override `delegate` to return `_externalDelegate` but that caused some strange side effects (there must be internal code that depends on the actual delegate to be returned).